# Federation requires either a User Pool or Identity Pool in config error - Amplify + Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm having trouble finding information on how to associate my existing user pool with amplify using Angular. Currently when I click on my **Login** with Google button, I get this error:

[image]

The `amplify configure` CMD doesn't give an option about a .config file. So I'm not sure how to establish this relationship to make that error go away. I already did `amplify init` and it went through successfully.

**How do I make the connection to the User Pool?**

I appreciate any help!

The error happens when I click on the Google login button in login component:

**login.component.ts**

```js
async signInWithGoogle(): Promise < void > {
    const socialResult =
        await this.authService.socialSignIn(AuthService.GOOGLE);
    console.log('google Result:', socialResult);
}
```

**auth.service.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  CognitoUserAttribute,
  CognitoUser,
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUserSession
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import Auth, { CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider } from '@aws-amplify/auth'
import { Hub, ICredentials } from '@aws-amplify/core'
import { User } from './user.model';
import awsconfig from '../aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
const POOL_DATA = {
  UserPoolId: 'us-east-1_fSgUd7X4m',
  ClientId: '<my id was here>'
};

const userPool = new CognitoUserPool(POOL_DATA);

@Injectable({ providedIn: "root" })
export class AuthService {
  authIsLoading = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authDidFail = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  authStatusChanged = new Subject<boolean>();
  public loggedIn: boolean;

  private _authState: Subject<CognitoUser | any> = new Subject<CognitoUser | any>();
  authState: Observable<CognitoUser | any> = this._authState.asObservable();

  public static SIGN_IN = 'signIn';
  public static SIGN_OUT = 'signOut';
  public static GOOGLE = CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider.Google;
  registeredUser: CognitoUser;
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  signUp(username: string, email: string, password: string): void {

    this.authIsLoading.next(true);
    const user: User = {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      password: password
    };
    const attrList: CognitoUserAttribute[] = [];
    const emailAttribute = {
      Name: 'email',
      Value: user.email
    };
    attrList.push(new CognitoUserAttribute(emailAttribute));
    userPool.signUp(user.username, user.password, attrList, null, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err)
        this.authDidFail.next(true);
        this.authIsLoading.next(false);
        return;
      }
      this.authDidFail.next(false);
      this.authIsLoading.next(false);
      this.registeredUser = result.user;
    });
    return;
  }

  confirmUser(username: string, code: string) {
    this.authIsLoading.next(true);
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool
    };
    const cognitUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    cognitUser.confirmRegistration(code, true, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        this.authDidFail.next(true);
        this.authIsLoading.next(false);
        return;
      }
      this.authDidFail.next(false);
      this.authIsLoading.next(false);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    });
  }
  socialSignIn(provider: CognitoHostedUIIdentityProvider): Promise<ICredentials> {

    return Auth.federatedSignIn({ provider: provider });
  }
  signIn(username: string, password: string): void {
    this.authIsLoading.next(true);
    const authData = {
      Username: username,
      Password: password
    };
    const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails(authData);
    const userData = {
      Username: username,
      Pool: userPool
    };
    const cognitoUser = new CognitoUser(userData);
    const that = this;
    cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
      onSuccess(result: CognitoUserSession): void {
        that.authStatusChanged.next(true);
        that.authDidFail.next(false);
        that.authIsLoading.next(false);
        console.log(result);
      },
      onFailure(err): void {
        that.authDidFail.next(true);
        that.authIsLoading.next(false);
        console.log(err);
      }
    });
    this.authStatusChanged.next(true); // create user with cognito data

    return;
  }

  getAuthenticatedUser() {
    return userPool.getCurrentUser();
  }

  logout() {
    this.getAuthenticatedUser().signOut();
    this.authStatusChanged.next(false);
  }

  isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
    const user = this.getAuthenticatedUser();
    const obs = Observable.create((observer) => {
      if (!user) {
        observer.next(false);
      } else {
        user.getSession((err, session) => {
          if (err) {
            observer.next(false);
          } else {
            if (session.isValid()) {
              observer.next(true);
            } else {
              observer.next(false);
            }
          }
        });
      }
      observer.complete();
    });
    return obs;
  }

  initAuth() {
    this.isAuthenticated().subscribe(
      (auth) => this.authStatusChanged.next(auth)
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you create the pool in cognito?

Comment: I already created the user pool in aws console > cognito. I'm also able to login and authenticate with the user pool so that part is hooked up.

Comment: when you create your pool and your client pool, are you added google as provider?

Comment: Yes I filled that out. https://postimg.cc/564DcQkH

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [AWS Amplify auth documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/start/q/platform/js#re-use-existing-authentication-resource) indicates the following regarding re-use of existing AWS Cognito resources:

> If you want to re-use an existing authentication resource from AWS (e.g. Amazon Cognito UserPool or Identity Pool), update `Amplify.configure()` method with the following information.

```js
import Amplify, { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {

        // REQUIRED only for Federated Authentication - Amazon Cognito Identity Pool ID
        identityPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X:XXXXXXXX-XXXX-1234-abcd-1234567890ab',

        // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
        region: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Federated Identity Pool Region 
        // Required only if it's different from Amazon Cognito Region
        identityPoolRegion: 'XX-XXXX-X',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito User Pool ID
        userPoolId: 'XX-XXXX-X_abcd1234',

        // OPTIONAL - Amazon Cognito Web Client ID (26-char alphanumeric string)
        userPoolWebClientId: 'a1b2c3d4e5f6g7h8i9j0k1l2m3',

        // OPTIONAL - Enforce user authentication prior to accessing AWS resources or not
        mandatorySignIn: false,

        // OPTIONAL - Configuration for cookie storage
        // Note: if the secure flag is set to true, then the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol
        cookieStorage: {
        // REQUIRED - Cookie domain (only required if cookieStorage is provided)
            domain: '.yourdomain.com',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie path
            path: '/',
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie expiration in days
            expires: 365,
        // OPTIONAL - See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite
            sameSite: "strict" | "lax",
        // OPTIONAL - Cookie secure flag
        // Either true or false, indicating if the cookie transmission requires a secure protocol (https).
            secure: true
        },

        // OPTIONAL - customized storage object
        storage: MyStorage,

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set the authentication flow type. Default is 'USER_SRP_AUTH'
        authenticationFlowType: 'USER_PASSWORD_AUTH',

        // OPTIONAL - Manually set key value pairs that can be passed to Cognito Lambda Triggers
        clientMetadata: { myCustomKey: 'myCustomValue' },

         // OPTIONAL - Hosted UI configuration
        oauth: {
            domain: 'your_cognito_domain',
            scope: ['phone', 'email', 'profile', 'openid', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            responseType: 'code' // or 'token', note that REFRESH token will only be generated when the responseType is code
        }
    }
});

// You can get the current config object
const currentConfig = Auth.configure();
```

Please, verify that the `awsconfig` variable include a similar information or modify it as necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I got a little closer, but it's still not working perfectly. When I click the login with google button now, I get https://postimg.cc/4mBqJJZ1 . Here's my updated auth service with some notes of where the values came from: https://pastebin.com/u6BYFJcq  Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I also tried setting the callback url and signout url to ```http://localhost:4200/``` or ```http://localhost:4200``` in app client settings based on posts similar to this error

Comment: The error indicated by Cognito is ```redirect_mismatch```. This error could happen when there is some inconsistencies between the values provided for the ```redirect_uri``` parameter in the OAuth2 flow. AWS amplify populates this field based on the value of the configuration property ```redirectSignIn```under ```oauth```, which takes the value ```redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000/'``` in your code. Please, verify that this is the value also configured in your App Client Settings Callback URL property in Cognito, and that it also match the URL in which your frontend is running.

Comment: Please, also verify that in your Google OAuth2 Client configuration you have included ```https://ecommercetest.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse``` - as suppose that it is the right value according to your code - under ```Authorized redirect URIs```

Comment: Here's how the app client page in cognito looks like: https://postimg.cc/4KR9B2xH . I also tried based on your last comment enabling OAuth 2.0 with the current configuration    https://postimg.cc/fJjnVJ04 . I enabled profile only because that's the scope I set when configuring google. https://postimg.cc/MfBwP5TX  With callback url and signout url set to ```http://localhost:3000/``` I get  https://postimg.cc/bsP4fpVm I don't have a local node server running on localhost:3000 fyi so I feel like this could be an issue... I plan on using AWS lambda functions if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank for sharing your config. Please, in your app client settings page, under ```Enabled Identity Providers```, select the ```Google``` check box. Also, under ```Allowed OAuth Flows```, select at least the ```Implicit grant``` check box, and under ```Allowed OAuth Scopes```, select at least the ```email```, ```openid``` and ```profile``` check boxes. Also, do not forget to capture and map the Google's ```email``` attribute with the ```Email``` User pool attribute in the ```Attribute mapping``` section of your ```Google``` tab under ```Federation```.

Comment: It's not working yet, but I think I'm getting closer because ```Launch Hosted UI``` button in app client settings wouldn't work at all and now it atleast shows https://postimg.cc/N55BL1wK , but when you click continue with google I get https://postimg.cc/t7mH0YVp . In the app when I click login with google I get https://postimg.cc/4HYq4QhZ  Here is how it's configured now: https://postimg.cc/w1rzh3gw  and google section: https://postimg.cc/68WVd5Y4

Comment: As the error indicates, you need to configure in your Google OAuth2 client configuration, within the Google GCP or API developer console, the value ```https://ecommercetest.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idpresponse``` as an ```Authorized Redirect URL```. This configuration must be done in the Google API console, not the AWS Cognito one.

Comment: I made the recommended change in OAUTH credentials section of google developer console and now when I click ```Launch Hosted UI``` button in app client settings and then click continue with google, I get the email login screen so I think it's working on that part. When I choose an email I get this: https://postimg.cc/NyczYhck  but If I click sign in with google in my app, I get https://postimg.cc/rD6hC6K2  Do you think it has to do with localhost:3000 not having anything running? As I mentioned before, I was gonna use AWS Lambda functions for my app's backend

Comment: It is ok to use lambda or whatever you need as your backend. It is very important to understand that all this configuration is done at the frontend level. If your frontend is not running at ```http://localhost:3000/``` and instead it is running, like a typical angular cli app, on ```http:/localhost:4200/```, you must replace in the app configuration code and in the AWS Cognito console all the references to ```http://localhost:3000/``` with ```http:/localhost:4200/```. Please, can you try?

Comment: I made the following changes and when I try and click google login in my app now, it takes me straight to ```http://localhost:4200/``` instead of google login with the error in address bar and console ```OAuth Error handling auth response. Error: invalid_scope``` https://postimg.cc/N5N5MPYN  With Angular running on 4200 I  updated auth.service.ts ````redirectSigin``` and redirectSignOut``` fields https://postimg.cc/MfKFpGbr I also updated callback URL and sign out URL in app client settings https://postimg.cc/KkQ0w2S7. I updated google developer console as well: https://postimg.cc/MMry1KJL

Comment: Unhhh... Please, can you remove the ```aws.cognito.signin.user.admin``` ```scope``` from your app configuration and try again? The one in your image https://postimg.cc/MfKFpGbr. I mean, it must be an array that should include the above mentioned ```email```, ```profile``` and ``openid```.

Comment: I think it worked. I click login with google and it takes me to email selection and then it takes me to localhost:4200 root of my site. If I try and login again after that it takes me straight to root path of my site again. This is console network tab https://postimg.cc/gw0j8CqX

Comment: Nice!! I think so, it looks good. I'm happy to see that it finally worked.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: You are welcome!! I am glad to hear that the answer was helpful!